# Reference top level object in html using jquery

Tags: jquery, reference

I am trying to figure out how to use jquery to reference top level object in html (body) from any child element inside html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not clear why $("body") won't work.

see http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/

This can be used from anywhere and what child you are "in" does not matter.

---

Additional notes based on comments:

It really depends on each case.  If the need is relative (there is more than one table in the page) then using `parent()` and `closest()` will often be the best way.  In simpler pages, you can search for elements directly by ID.

Two examples:

A page with two lists where you want to move elements between one list and the other.  Since this functionality is defined as a page having just two lists then it makes sense to use the direct method.

A page with a dynamic list of users and dynamic addition of elements in a user's content (eg dynamic chat).  In  this case you want to use relative since each user's area will have the same elements and you want to modify that area relative to the user area.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to handle events being triggered by buttons in each table row. If I want jquery to reference an element outside a table/row it appears much easier to search for an element from top level, than trying to get out of a table and then search for this particular element.

Answer (score 0):

You can always  use `$.prev()` and `$.next()`

This `$.parent()` will return parent container

http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Or by selector:

`$('body')`

Comment: There would never be good a reason to use `#bodyID` since HTML can only have 1 body element and it would run slower.

Comment: You right.. but i remember bug in ie6 which required add id to the body.. anyway i fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
element.closest('body');
```

Though this is surely not practical, you should refer to body one time and cache the result in a variable, like:

```
body = $('body');
```

and then just refer to `body`.

Comment: Why do this?  HTML can only have one `<BODY>`, this would just run much slower than `$("BODY")`.

Comment: just wanted to show that there is `closest`, updated the answer to say it's not practical.